# Invalid JSON GET Request Express.js

Tags: ajax, json, node.js, express

While writing an API, I have come across a very thorny error: when I try to do a `res.send(INSERT JSON)` with a Content-Type header `application/json` (a default for most AJAX), I get an `invalid json` error. When I set the content-type to anything else (eg. `text/plain`), I get the correct response, but in order to use some front-end frameworks, I need to support `application/json`. Here is the actual error message:

```
Error: invalid json
    at Object.exports.error (/Users/Brad/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils.js:44:13)
    at IncomingMessage.module.exports (/Users/Brad/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/json.js:68:73)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:85:17)
    at IncomingMessage._emitEnd (http.js:366:10)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnMessageComplete [as onMessageComplete] (http.js:149:23)
    at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1680:22)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:410:27)
```

My server code is below:

```
app.configure(function () {
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.cookieParser('SALT'));
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static/'));
  app.use(express.session());
});

app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  res.send({'test': 'test'});
});
```

Here is an picture of my Postman setup--I am using the Postman Chrome extension to test my API:
[image]

Comment: That code looks just fine, and works fine too. What is generating the 'invalid json' error?

Comment: When I make a GET Request with `content-type` as `application/json`, I get the invalid JSON error. I'll ad the actual error to my question.

Comment: I think that means the data you are sending *to the server* isn't valid JSON. How are you testing this (which client)?

Comment: I am using the Postman extension on Chrome. I'm simply typing in the url (localhost:3000/users), setting it to make a GET request, and typing a header.

Comment: I installed Postman and did the same, running the server code you posted, and it works just fine.

Comment: Check out my update above for a picture of how I did my postman setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you want to be using Content-Type header in your servers response; not in your request Content-Type header.

When you use the Content-Type header in your request, Express will read the Content-Type and attempt to interpret the provided information as that Content-Type, in this case, as JSON. Because this is a GET request and thus has no body, Express is trying to interpret an empty string as JSON, which is giving you the error.

Comment: Yes, for a `GET` the server would expect an `Accepts` header that would be set with the same value (`application/json`).

Comment: Thanks for the `Accept` suggestion--that works really well in Postman. However, I am trying to connect this API to ember.js's RESTAdapter, which still gives the same error when it makes the GET request to the server.

Comment: The Accepts header is more the request letting the server know what the client is expecting. There is no guarantee that the server will actually return this.

Comment: Rather strange that I couldn't reproduce the issue with Postman, but good to see it's solved :)

Comment: @robertklep you can reproduce the issue with Postman by setting a Content-Type: application/json header and making a GET request to any Express server running. I believe that the bodyParser middleware has to be in use. The same issue can also be seen by sending a POST request with Content-Type: application/json and an empty body; but can easily be correctly by sending a body of '{}'.

Comment: @NickMitchinson that's how I tested, and it works just fine (Express@3.2.6, [gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/5698251), [screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1577733/demo.png)).